# Not able to compile the u-boot 2017.09

Tags: pi-3, linux, archlinux, cross-compilation, gcc

This is the OS info that I am using in my pi3 (BCM 2837) board.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.98-v7+ #1200 SMP Tue Feb 12 20:27:48 GMT 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

[ am I using the wrong OS by any chance ?]
when I tried to compile U-boot 2017.9 I got the below error sir:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export ARCH=arm64
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd u-boot-2017.09
pi@raspberrypi:~/u-boot-2017.09 $ make rpi_3_defconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/kconfig/zconf.hash.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
#
# configuration written to .config        
#
#
pi@raspberrypi:~/u-boot-2017.09 $ make all
make: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: Command not found
/bin/sh: 1: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
dirname: missing operand
Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config.h
  UPD     include/config.h
  CFG     u-boot.cfg
/bin/sh: 1: aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.autoconf:79: recipe for target 'u-boot.cfg' failed
make[1]: *** [u-boot.cfg] Error 1
make: *** No rule to make target 'include/config/auto.conf', needed by 'include/config/uboot.release'.  Stop.
pi@raspberrypi:~/u-boot-2017.09 $
```

Later by reading this error I tried to install gcc-aarch63 compiler but its showing like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# password
bash: password: command not found
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# clear
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi : Depends: gcc-5-arm-linux-gnueabi (>= 5.2.1-13cross1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linix-gnu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-aarch64-linix-gnu
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu : Depends: gcc-5-aarch64-linux-gnu (>= 5.2.1-13cross1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

on browsing I come across one solution i.e

```
#: apt-get update
#: apt-get dist-upgrade
#: reboot
```

but even after doing this I am not able to install the aarch-gnu compiler.

Without this compiler we cant install the xvisor as even the next steps also includes the cross compiling steps.

Comment: You should explain what your goal is, and work on the formatting. Currently it's hard to tell what part of your post belongs to the problem description, the commands you have tried, or error messages.

Comment: this appears to  be the only question in your post ... `am I using the wrong OS by any chance ?` ..... if the Pi3 boots correctly, then you are probably not using the wrong OS

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling **U-boot** from source you should first try to use the package from the default repository. It is pre compiled and well integrated into the Raspbian installation so you will avoid any compiling problems. Just install it with tools:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install u-boot-rpi u-boot-tools
```

Now you only have to configure it.